# Get the nth item from a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm getting some JSON Array data using this query:

```
$.getJSON(locationstring, function (result) {
    $.each(result, function (i, field) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

And it gets printed like this:

[image]

I need to get the values under the tag "formatted_address" in the 0th object (or 1st) of the Array, as displayed in the picture. How can I get this done?

This is to get the value "formatted_address" of the 0th array item from this link:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=7.243286200000001,80.61632869999999&sensor=true

Comment: `result.results[0].formatted_address`???

Comment: I have no clue why this post has so many down votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(locationstring, function (result) { 
    console.log(result.results[0].formatted_address);
});
```

The complete code, to get the thing you want. You don't need `$.each`

Comment: this returns a 'undefined' in the console mate

Comment: this screenshot is the console.log(?of what?)

Comment: locations returned by this JSON URL: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=7.243286200000001,80.61632869999999&sensor=true

Comment: @Earthling try being more consistent next time. you have a console.log in your code that was inside the loop, so I assumed the screenshot was from there.

Comment: @Earthling idk why returns 'undefined'. works for me http://i.imgur.com/1lKMg23.png

Comment: @Earthling or just use this 


$.getJSON(locationstring, function (result) { 
         console.log(result.results[0].formatted_address)
           
        });

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON(locationstring, function (result) {
    console.log(result.results[0].formatted_address);
});
```